# Kosher Supervision

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification

Is it okay for a food manufacturer to have two supervisions? (OU and Kof-K) If our raw materials are under OU supervision and our co-packing finished goods are under Kof-K. Do we need to streamline this to one company?

Comment: Many products have multiple certifications. Often they all use the same rav hamachshir. You should ask the two organizations about what to do.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40226

Comment: I can't tell you how common this! If you've been to a Jewish wedding, esp. in the Northeast U.S., Chantilly is the main cake / pastry supplier. All their boxes have 4 or 5 hechsherim. It's smart business for them. Mainly because of this, Chantilly pretty much has a monopoly on the simcha cake business.

Comment: This post is getting some close votes for being practical Halacha. I assume this is based on the first-person wording in the last two sentences and the oddly specific choice of OU and Chaf-K in the first one. If this is indeed a practical question, perhaps you should check out our [Meta post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) regarding such questions.

Comment: I should have posted this first, but welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you register your account, you can gain access to all sorts of neat features. You might also want to check out our [tour].

Comment: This puts up the price of kosher food. That cant be a good thing. Each hechsher has to be paid for.